# JQuery fixed top nav, variables change on resize, disabled on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been struggling to get some JQuery code working on a new site. It involves fixing a navigation div to the top of window once a scroll point has been passed.

There are 2 divs that change height when the page is resized and the whole action should only happen when @media (min-width: 768px).

This is the basic structure at the top of my site:

```
<div id="x-topbar-wrap"></div>
<div id="nav-top-wrap">
    <div id="nav-top-inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="x-slider-container"></div>
```

I want to create two variables, that update as the window is resized:

```
var topbarHeight = $('#x-topbar-wrap').outerHeight();
var navtopHeight = $('#nav-top-wrap').outerHeight();
```

...and use them when the window is scrolled:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= topbarHeight) {
        $('#nav-top-inner').addClass('fixed max');
        $('.x-slider-container').css('margin-top', navtopHeight + 'px');
    } else {
        $('#nav-top-inner').removeClass('fixed max');
        $('.x-slider-container').css('margin-top', '0px');
    }
});
```

The class 'fixed' is as follows and therefore is disabled on mobile devices.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #nav-top-inner.fixed {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        z-index:1050;
    }
}
```

The margin-top on .x-slider-container should also be disabled on mobile devices, but because its size is variable I was trying to do a media query check like this:

```
if ($("#nav-top-inner").css('position') == 'fixed') {
    $('.x-slider-container').css('margin-top', navtopheight + 'px');
} else {
    $('.x-slider-container').css('margin-top', '0px');
}
```

I would very much appreciate some help pulling it all together, particularly where the two variables update as the page resizes.

I've got it to work fairly well without the resizing, but was experiencing different results between Chrome and Safari weirdly.

And here is the website: http://www.pricestudios.co.uk/

Thank you,

Sam

Comment: is the windows resizing constantly or it has a certain size from the beginning ? might want to take a look at https://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: Hi Mihai, thanks for your comment. Yes, I think .resize() is the right approach, but I've been struggling with where and how to best employ it in my code...

Comment: so you want to add the fixed height and margin when both scrolling and resizing the window, correct ?

Comment: Hi Mihai, here's the website: http://www.pricestudios.co.uk/ . The coloured blocks at the top should 'fix' to the top of the window when the window has scrolled past 'topbarHeight'. At the same time the slider underneath should have a margin added equal to 'navtopHeight'. But, 'topbarHeight' and 'navtopHeight' will change if the window is resized and therefore need to be updated.

Comment: use the resize method to update the values of the topbarHeight and navtopHeight on each resize of the window. This will assure when the scrolling event is encountered, you will have the appropriate values for them.
Ps: compute the values one time outside of the resize method, in case the window is not resized, you would have the original values

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with and it seems to be working well. Any thoughts / recommendations on cleaning it up would be appreciated.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    setTimeout(function(){

        var topbarHeight, navtopHeight;

        function setSizes() {
            topbarHeight = $('#x-topbar-wrap').outerHeight();
            navtopHeight = $('#nav-top-wrap').outerHeight();
        }

        setSizes();

        $(window).resize(setSizes);

        $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() >= topbarHeight) {
                $('#nav-top-inner').addClass('fixed max');
                if ($("#nav-top-inner").css('position') == 'fixed') {
                    $('.x-slider-container').css('margin-top',
                        navtopHeight + 'px');
                } else {
                    $('.x-slider-container').css('margin-top',
                        '0px');
                }
            } else {
                $('#nav-top-inner').removeClass('fixed max');
                $('.x-slider-container').css('margin-top', '0px');
            }
        });
    },1000);
});
```

Comment: Why are you doing this every 1 second ? Is there a reason for it ?

Comment: Hi Mihai, the setTimeout is just meant to run at the beginning leaving 1 second after (document).ready in order to give the page a better chance of returning the correct outerHeight for the variables. I don't think it's repeating is it?